# bpy copy object's name to clipboard

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Is there a way to copy a selected object's name to the clipboard. I have a script that I would like the last line to copy the object's name, so I can easily paste in a search box.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows:

```
import bpy
import subprocess

def copy2clip(txt):
    cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|clip'
    return subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)

copy2clip(bpy.context.object.name)
```

On Mac:

```
    cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|pbcopy'
```

On Linux:

```
    cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|xclip'
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) works like a charm !

Comment: I have noticed that when trying to use the code with an object that has the & sign (text&box, a&m etc.) I get an error, I suspect it is something to do with the & clashes with cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|clip'. what do you think? @Crantisz

Comment: Maybe adding backslash before `&` or adding `"` helps

Comment: Thanks, " seems to work but not the backslash..
Is there a way I could amend the code to avoid this error?

Comment: For reference this looks like it is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/41029935/7092409